# How to pop up a childwindow from another .xam file button click?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, button, silverlight-5.0

I am working in `silverlight` and i am a beginner. I have created a MainPage.xaml file in which i have a button. Now i have created  another page ButtonData.xaml in the 
same project It contains the data to be displayed on button click (must be poped).

Now what i want is to display the page ButtonData.xaml on button click (this button is present on MainPage.xaml).

How to achieve it ?

My try is :

```
public partial class MainPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = ProgramViewModel.GetInstance();
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ButtonData.show(); //But do not show the ButtonData.xaml in fact it will give error because it is an .xaml file
    }
 }
```

I know i am absolutley wrong but could some one tell me how to do it ?

Comment: You want a ChildWindow? If not, you need to use the Frame

Comment: @Sajeetharan something liek child window but when i create childwindow it popups differently because we cannnot view other data oe a childwindow is popuped. Do you anothger alternative ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan do you think it is possible ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan how will i do that if it is a childwindow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a ChildWindow, this how you open it,

```
    AddChildButton objChild = new AddChildButton();
    objChild.Show();
```

Comment: But this childWindow i have added in my project by clicking Add->NewItem-> then child window. and i have created some buttons on it using xaml code.(supposed i saved it by AddChildButton.xaml) and the way you do that way i need to add button programatically on it but i already have it using xaml code .

Comment: @user234839 I dont get what you are saying

Comment: I am saying that you have createdthis child widow programatically(c# code) but i already added child window in my project like this Add->NewItem-> then child window and named it "AddChildButton.xaml" and saved in my project. Now when i try to do in MainPage.cs AddChildButton.Show() then it do not recognizes show function. (But i have not done "ChildWindow AddChildButton= new ChildWindow();" because i already have created this childwindow  AddChildButton.xaml    but by xaml not like you as you have done). Have you understood  now ?

Comment: @user234839 check the modified one